# Does @RedisHash TTL works with RedisTemplate directly?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, ttl

I read several articles/example from Internet, and I'm understand that @RedisHash annotation is always used together with CRUDRepository.

I'm currently want to use the TimeToLive feature that provided under the @RedisHash.

But may I know if @RedisHash(timeToLive) is able to work directly with RedisTemplate?

For example, I have a @RedisHash model

```
@RedisHash(timeToLive = 2L)
@Getter
@Setter
public class RedisModel implements Serializable {

private String key;
private String value;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return key + "::" + value;
}
```

}

I tried to save the RedisHash model through redistemplate

```
RedisModel model = new RedisModel();
model.setKey("mykey");
model.setValue("myvalue");

redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("key_here", model);
```

I tested above changes but it seems the key didn't get auto expired. It's remained there in the redis server.

---

I also aware that redisTemplate did provide expire and expireAt methods for us to handle TTL. I tested this part and it works fine.
However, I would want to know if the RedisHash(TTL) can do the same magic with redisTemplate.
Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Short answer, "NO". The `@RedisHash` annotation can only be applied to entities handled by the Spring Data Redis Repository infrastructure. Spring Data Redis Templates do not take annotations like `@RedisHash` or `@Indexed`, etc, into account.